# Importance of 'Type Tables' (like a BOOK_TYPE table) when defining models using ORM (like ActiveRecord) for web APIs

Tags: javascript, sql, database, rest, orm

By Type Table, I'm talking about things like `type` in a `books` table which can map out to a `book_types` table that lists possible types.

Most implementations I see and just define a string column and use validation to compare it against a set of types `['hardcover', 'softcover', 'ebook']`

Is it worth it to create another model `BookType` and establish a one-to-many relationship with `Book` table?

Answer (score 1):

The reason tables like this are used in relational models is to avoid data duplication in the database. Each type string will exist on a single row in the type table; this means if you ever need to change that string, you don't have to update every row that uses it. It might not seem likely right now, or likely in every case, but not setting it up in a normalised manner could prove painful at some later point.

There are potentially other benefits:

- You might save space by having an integer foreign key ID on each row instead of a large string.
- If it would be useful to have a short code alongside a longer descriptive field for each type, a separate type table will save space and make it easier to maintain the description field in the same way as described above.
- Such a descriptive field might well be helpful if someone needs to use the data for reporting or business intelligence purposes later on down the line, in cases where a single-word type isn't already clear-cut.